# How to ignore an executable file in linux that does not have an extension in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a C++ code and after executing it in codeblocks, it generate another two files(ugly.o, and ugly). The latter doesn't have an extension and it is executable. I can ignore it manually by typing in `.gitignore` as `ugly`. However it is not a dynamic way. I have to explicitly add another filename in .gitignore when I created a new one. Do you know other ways to make it dynamic, that will treat any file that does't have an extension will be ignored?

Comment: Are you going to create and delete many projects in the repository, each with different names? Are you going to create a lot of executable files all the time? If not then I really don't see this as a problem. You have your workspace, you have a fixed set of projects in the workspace, and you only need to add the projects executable to the `.gitignore` file *once* and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions, either put all these files into a separate folder e.g `_notused/` and `.gitignore` the whole folder (this is what i do)

or add an extension to that file and ignore it explicitly in `.gitignore`

or just use the filename (even without extension and/or as a unique pattern, as similar answers have suggested) in `.gitingore` (havent tried that but it might work)